# Python IDLE doesn't recognize numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy, import, python-import

A very simple thing - I downloaded python 3.8 and installed numpy. Upon making a very basic program that uses a numpy function, I get an error. I captured all the info that I think is relevant for now:

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/numpytest.py", line 6, in <module>
    a=sigmoid(2)
  File "C:/Python/numpytest.py", line 4, in sigmoid
    return 1/(1+exp(-x))
NameError: name 'exp' is not defined
```

I'm guessing it isn't even importing numpy but no idea why.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.exp(x)` to access Numpy's `exp()` function.

Otherwise, import Numpy as:

```
from numpy import *
```

to use `exp()` without any prefix.

Comment: better stick with the `np` import and use `np.exp`

Comment: That was quick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
import numpy as np
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
a=sigmoid(2)
print(a)
```

You need to call the `np` class then the `exp` function

Also, it is better to copy the text rather than take a picture of it.